# How to set model to IEnumerable in MVC3.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I want to use a view with model as IEnumerable type some thing like this

```
@model IEnumerable<WCG.Data.EntityObjects.FaxHistory>
```

Note:-I have classes as FaxHistory.cs(Main class where variables are declared)

```
FaxHistoryBo.cs
FaxHistoryDao.cs
IfaxHIstoryDao.cs
FaxHistoryController.cs
FaxHistorymodel.cs
```

Comment: Have you tried using the fully qualified namespace? System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable ?

Comment: Yes I have and am setting error. The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'WCG.Web.Models.FaxHistoryModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[WCG.Data.EntityObjects.FaxHistory]'.

Comment: That means the object you're passing into the view is of the wrong type. Can you put a breakpoint there and see what type it is in the controller?

Comment: Thanks mate for ur help now its up and running was some problem in the action method